# Change variable on the end of the month to a new value

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Hi i have a script that sorts and label emails, it adds them to "sent" or "not sent" and per month.

So the script has two variables that points what label should be used.

```
  var SentLabel = "October/2014 - December/Sent";
  var NotSentLabel = "October/2014 - December/Not Sent";
```

Is there any way i could perhaps change my variable value's each month so in this case at **October 31 23:59** the value in  `var SentLabel` is set to  `var SentLabel = "November/2014 - December/Sent";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can do that by declaring the variable as below:

```
var monthInWords= [ "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
    "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December" ];

var d = new Date();

var SentLabel = monthInWords[d.getMonth()] + "/2014 - December/Sent";
```

Comment: Thanks Arvind, but it tells me: ReferenceError: "d" has not defined. (line 7, file "test")Dismiss

Comment: d is for new Date(), i.e. a date object declaration returning today's date.

Comment: Please run the function in the this link and view the output using View -> Logs from the menu 

https://script.google.com/d/1ltU6VWnN-_gy30lyCo7u6HmUHZRJ4NoHtGCtjnOWMoBMnVex8Q4Lpbg5/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: It worked not, something temporary maybee, Thanks ALOT Arvind!